# Segmentation fault when using classical matrix instead of dynamically allocated

Tags: c, matrix

As far as i know this two ways to create a matrix should be identical:

First way:

```
int i;
int **matrix = (int**)malloc(R*sizeof(int*));
for (i=0; i<R; i++)
    matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(C*sizeof(int));
```

Second way:

```
int matrix[R][C];
```

with R and C declared as:

```
#define R 3
#define C 5
```

My question is, when i pass the second way declared matrix to a function like this:

```
void myfunction(int **m, int rows, int columns);
```

with the code:

```
myfunction(matrix,R,C);
```

why does it give me a Segmentation fault as soon as i try to touch the values inside the matrix?

The same happens when i pass the first way declared matrix to a function like this:

```
void myfunction(int m[][C], int rows, int columns);
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first way allocates an array of pointers to allocated arrays of int.
The 2nd way allocates a single array and uses the C parameter to calculate the correct offset.

They are not interchangeable.

See [the bottom part of this page](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_arrays.html) for the differences.

Comment: thank you, that page explained the issue quite well and i think i finally understand now.

Comment: ok, no. i thought i got it but i didn't. why does it work when i interchange the two ways inside the main, but it stops working when i pass the same pointer in the "wrong" way to a function?
this works:
        http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/9590/9per.png
this works too:
        http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/7201/uogp.png
but doing the same from inside a function (with the interchanged prototype from above) doesn't work.

Comment: if you declare `int a[R][C]`, you are making a single big block of memory.  `a` "points" to the beginning, and the compiler uses the declaration to jump to the right point when you access it with `a[x][y]`,   If you pass it to a function expecting an `int**` and write `**a`, the function essentially says "What does `a` point to?" It finds the first array element, and then says "ok, now what does that location point to?".  Then it goes and treats your data like a pointer and you get the segfault.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing memory **out of bounds** here:

```
for (i=0; i<C; i++)
    matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(C*sizeof(int));
```

Your `R = 3` and `C = 5`

You allocated memory for `R` **`int pointers`** then, for `C` pointers you are allocating space for `C` integer variables.

(Replacing variables with values):

You allocated memory for 3 **`int pointers`** then, for 5 pointers you are allocating space for 5 integer variables.

In your FIRST case:

It should give Seg. Fault as soon as you access `matrix[3]`, but anyways it is an Undefined Behaviour, you can't say anything.

In your SECOND case:

The code should work fine, unless you do a same kind of mistake (Mem Access Out-of-bounds) inside `myfunction()`.

Comment: sorry, it was just a distraction, not the point of the question.

thanks for answering by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the array out of bounds. Then the result is undefined. This line should be corrected as follows

```
for (i=0; i<R; i++)
    matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(C*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: sorry, it was just a distraction, not the point of the question.

thanks for answering by the way.